# Firebase events as conversions in Google Ads not working

Tags: firebase, google-ads-api

After importing our Firebase app events in Google Ads as conversions, their status stays at "no recent conversions". The events are recordeding fine in Firebase.

- Both our native iOS and Android app are implemented, but none show conversions in Google Ads
- The package name of one of our apps was updated
- We unlinked Google Ads from Firebase and linked it again, but that didn't work either
- We are talking about custom events (an in-app action) and native events (like first open)

It seems like we can't really delete conversions. We can delete and re-enable, but can't "start over".

How can we make recording our events as conversions work?

Comment: I have same problem, Can you solve this ?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far... :-)

Comment: I guess solved this problem, try add appstore id into your firebase account from project settings on firebase.and then you will see conversations in your google ads.

Comment: I have already my app store id into my firebase account, Still It happening for me, Any working solution?

Comment: I've already added my app store ID to my Firebase account, but I'm still experiencing the same issue. Is there any solution available?

Answer (score 13):

The answer was hiding in the comment made by @Akif Demirezen.

On Firebase, go to project settings 
[image: Project Settings]

Under "Your apps" section, make sure to fill the "App Store ID" field, you can find this information on your App Store connect page, under Apple ID

[image: Apple ID]

Comment: It worked. Also make sure that you have linked google analytics and Google ads in Project settings -> Integration in firbase.

Comment: We are not using an IOS app but facing the same issue in an android app, Any working solution?

Comment: @KhubaibRaza, google should have a smoother integration since they are the owner of both firebase and google play, try setting it up based on their tutorial. I don't recall that you need to enter app-id or the sort

Comment: I've already added my app store ID to my Firebase account, but I'm still experiencing the same issue. Is there any viable solution available?

Comment: wow thankss. It worked.