# Firebase events into Google Ads conversions is not functioning properly

Tags: ios, firebase, admob

After importing the events from my Firebase application into Google Ads as conversions, their status remains "no recent conversions", even after 5 days of an ongoing campaign. All conversion events are correctly recorded in Firebase. The "first_open" event is recorded in Google Ads but the "in_app_purchase" event is not. (Although both are correctly recorded in Firebase).

- My Firebase account and Google Ads are linked.
- I have my App Store ID registered in Firebase (as recommended here [Firebase events as conversions in Google Ads not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461654/firebase-events-as-conversions-in-google-ads-not-working))

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

@AkinoAvx13, we're having the same problem.  I found this on a Google Support thread:

> For anyone still stuck here, we had everything set up correctly but
> still seeing no conversions recorded for an iOS campaign and found the
> solution.
>
> Following the advice from Steve Fitzjohn above (RE:
> AdSupport.framework), we noticed that you can have Firebase
> implemented and working, however there is a secondary step that the
> dev team may have missed.
>
> In our case, this AdSupport framework wasn't implemented. As soon as
> the dev team completed this we started seeing conversions being
> reported within Google Ads. Problem solved. I'd recommend having
> this checked out.

Link: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/analytics-adsupport

We haven't implemented this, but it's worth trying.  We plan to get this done in the next week, so I'll post back with results.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll give it a try too and let you know the results. See you soon

Comment: Hi @byron, do you have any news about it?

Comment: @AkinoAvx13 it didn't seem to have any effect.  We're still seeing "No recent conversions"

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this?